# Idiom or saying about doing things well or doing them to the very best of your ability or achieving perfection

Tags: idiom-requests

Hi when I set my self a task I usually like to do it to the best of my ability or spend a lot of time doing working on it so that the out come of the project goes well, I have heard a couple of saying that I like to use “ I don’t do things in halves” or “quality over quantity” or “if your going to do something might as well do it properly or not at all” or “it won’t fail because of me” or something like “you’ve put this much effort you may as well finish it off properly!”

Does anyone have any idioms or sayings that they like to use that run along these lines

Thanks for your answers in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've a couple of suggestions..

You could say you're a **perfectionist** - a person who refuses to accept any standard short of perfection.

You **give it your all** - referring to you giving 100% of your focus to something.

Answer (score 1):

**dive into**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dive+into+(something))

> 2. To start doing something **enthusiastically**

As in:

> We just dove into fixing up our house.

Answer (score 1):

This is the idiom I would use in such a circumstance:

> If a job is worth doing, it's worth doing well.

See [this article](https://www.bookbrowse.com/expressions/detail/index.cfm/expression_number/537/if-a-jobs-worth-doing-its-worth-doing-well) for further information.

Note: I have been known to adapt this in the following way:

> If a job is worth doing, it's worth doing well. And if it's worth doing well, it's worth hiring a professional.