# Idiom about doing things right way?

Tags: idioms

Any idiom do you know means like"we'll do this one time but the hard way"?

Comment: Does the question mean that you consider the 'right way' to be the 'hard way'?

Comment: yes, we'll maybe struggle to do that job but in the end, we'll never spend time on that specific job

Comment: "If you don't have time to do it right, when will you have time to do it over?" from basketball coach John Wooden.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, but "[If a job's worth doing, it's worth doing well](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+a+thing+is+worth+doing%2C+it%27s+worth+doing+well)."

Comment: If you will never spend time on that job, it is a [**lost cause**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lost_cause).

Comment: _yes, we'll maybe struggle to do that job but in the end, we'll never spend time on that specific job_. I think you need to add the word 'again' to that to give _yes, we'll maybe struggle to do that job but in the end, we'll never spend time on that specific job **again**_

Comment: As refined in comments, it's a duplicate of [Idiom or saying about doing things well or doing them to the very best of your ability](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464274/idiom-or-saying-about-doing-things-well-or-doing-them-to-the-very-best-of-your-a/464294#464294).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can immediately think of the following

[Don't spoil the ship for a ha'porth of tar](https://www.lexico.com/definition/don%27t_spoil_the_ship_for_a_ha%27p%27orth_of_tar). (Old saying. A ha'porth was a half-penny-worth - a small denomination of currency)

[to be slow but sure](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/slow+but+sure.html)

[If a job's worth doing, it's worth doing well](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+a+thing+is+worth+doing%2C+it%27s+worth+doing+well)
(As mentioned by @Weather Vane)

[A stitch in time saves nine](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stitch+in+time+saves+nine)  (Traditional saying)

Comment: I also found "once and for all" almost similar.